# Agregar texto a un video reproducido en un JFXPanel

Tags: java, video

estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio en la que reproduzco un video en un JFXPanel (es lo que encontré para reproducir videos) y se muestra texto sobre el video, texto definido por el usuario, sobreescribiendo el método 'paint' del JFXPanel piso el video, hay alguna manera de poner alguna especie de panel delante del video y ahí agregar el texto? O ir por algún otro camino, el objetivo es agregarle texto dinámico a un video en una aplicación java (utilizo librerías swing).
Saludos y desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Ya resolví este tema, es tan simple como meterle al panel JFXPanel un JLabel y listo, el video se reproduce en el fondo del panel y uno puede agregarle componentes swing por encima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolví este tema, es tan simple como meterle al panel `JFXPanel` un `JLabel` y listo, el video se reproduce en el fondo del panel y uno puede agregarle componentes `swing` por encima.

Comment: Gracias por compartir la solución, recuerda que puedes [aceptar tu propia respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.